# Android permissions overrided by Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap 3.2 project. I am building this project to Android using:

```
phonegap build android
```

The project Manifest.xml generated contains the RECORD_AUDIO permission. However, I do not need this permission. If I remove it, the next time I run the build command, the permission comes back. I makes my deployment cycle a hassle with many manual modifications.

How can I prevent phonegap of always adding it? Or how can I add the required info to the config.xml file to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If it keeps getting defined at build time, check your config.xml if you have it specified there?

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

That would cause it to get added again at build.